# class argument with coding style

Tags: php, class, methods, coding-style

I have a question about the script code below:

```
ClassName::method("AnotherClassName@method");
```

How do you make code like that?

And I want to return it using:

```
return $AnotherClassName->method();
```

Comment: you can go through this docs [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your static class could simply be an alias (of sorts) for [call_user_func()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php#example-6374):

```
<?php
class ClassHelper
{
    public static function get($classmeth)
    {
        # Replace @ with :: as noted in the call_user_func() documentation
        return call_user_func(str_replace('@', '::', $classmeth));
    }
}
```

So essentially this:

```
$result = ClassHelper::get("AnotherClassName@someMethod");
```

is the equivalent of:

```
$Class  = new AnotherClassName();
$result = $Class->someMethod();
```